# Isolate text (path) in a vector if there are 4 different files available

Tags: r, regex

I have files in various subfolders with a varying naming pattern (like: yyyy-mm-dd_random_FAM_random.txt).

I have isolated the path of files I need with:

```
path_to_files <- "/path/to/files/with/subfolders/
list_of_files <- list.files(path=path_to_files,
                            recursive=T, 
                            pattern='201[0-9]-.*(FAM|SRY|STD|VIC).*\\.txt', 
                            full.names=T)
```

I need only those paths where there are exactly 1 file containing "FAM", "SRY", "STD", "VIC" in each subfolder. So I want to search for all strings that are similar except for the .*(FAM|SRY|STD|VIC).* part. in each subfolder.

If parts of path_to_files looks like:

```
[1] "/path/to/files/with/subfolders/subfolder.n/yyyy-mm-dd_random_FAM_random.txt"
[2] "/path/to/files/with/subfolders/subfolder.n/yyyy-mm-dd_random_SRY_random.txt"
[3] "/path/to/files/with/subfolders/subfolder.n/yyyy-mm-dd_random_STD_random.txt"
[4] "/path/to/files/with/subfolders/subfolder.n/yyyy-mm-dd_random_VIC_random.txt"
[5] "/path/to/files/with/subfolders/subfolder.n/yyyy-mm-dd_random_VIC_random-differs.txt"
```

I want to omit all strings that contain

```
"/path/to/files/with/subfolders/subfolder.n/"
```

How do I solve this with R?

Comment: `grepl` should do the trick. You can use it to omit all strings that contain "subfolder.n", and to find those that contain "yyyy-mm-dd_random_XXX_random.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with:

```
## 1. get vector of files to be used
path_to_files <- "J:/Diagnostik/cffDNA-LightCycler/LC-Läufe 2016"
list_of_files <- list.files(path=path_to_files,
                        recursive=T,
                        pattern='201[0-9]-.*(FAM|SRY|STD|VIC).*.txt',
                        full.names=T)

list_of_files.df <- data.frame(path_filename = list_of_files, 
                               path = dirname(list_of_files), 
                               file = basename(list_of_files))

# identify all folders where there are n*4 files with pattern: '201[0-9]-.*(FAM|SRY|STD|VIC).*.txt' 
library(dplyr)
complete_folders <- subset(summarize(group_by(list_of_files.df, path), 
                      count= n(), modulus.4 = (count %% 4 == 0)), modulus.4 == TRUE)
complete_folders <- as.character(complete_folders$path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your strings follow the same format, then simply,

```
x <- c("/path/to/files/with/subfolders/subfolder1/yyyy-mm-dd_random_FAM_random.txt", "/path/to/files/with/subfolders/subfolder.n/yyyy-mm-dd_random_SRY_random.txt")
x[!grepl(".n/", x)]
#[1] "/path/to/files/with/subfolders/subfolder1/yyyy-mm-dd_random_FAM_random.txt"
```

Based on your commend, is this what you need?

```
str_extract(x, '/([^/]*)$')
#[1] "/yyyy-mm-dd_random_FAM_random.txt" "/yyyy-mm-dd_random_SRY_random.txt"
```

Comment: Sry my question might have been confusing. I think my typo added to the confusion. My issue was not with the subfolder names but with the contents of the file.

Comment: what is your expected output?